# Iphone listen through headphones while recording through its microphone?

Tags: audio-recording, headphones, iphone, clicks

Can’t find a simple solution to this.

I have prepared a clicktrack for the singers in my chorus.

For a singer who only has an iphone, is it possible to listen through headphones, and simultaneously record his or her singing using the microphone on the iphone?

For example, I have an iphone se with ios 13, and can record fine with “Voice Memos” on this iPhone.

What I’m wondering is, can I use headphones on the iphone’s headphone jack, so I can listen to the click track while simultaneously recording with Voice Memos?

The point is to record the singer’s sound, without capturing the click track they are listening to, at the same, on the same iphone.

Advice for simple headphones, and an appropriate app would be very much appreciated. This is an amateur group of singers. Final product does not have to be ready for sale.

-Bruce

Answer (score 1):

Headphones and garage band are all you need to do that on an iPhone.